# Apache tomcat : Permanent redirect not working

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ssl, url-rewriting

I have deployed a WAR file on our domain which has https. Currently, the problem is if I hit below domain :

```
https://www.domain-name.com
domain-name.com
```

Then I have no issues, but as soon as I try :

```
https://domain-name.com
```

I get a untrusted connection error. For this, I decided to add a urlrewrite.xml file in WEB-INF folder and the below settings for web.xml:

urlrewrite.xml :

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>https://domain-name.com</from>
        <to>https://www.domain-name.com</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

And I added this in web.xml :

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Dependency in POM.xml :

```
   <!-- URL redirect dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Unfortunately it's not helping. How can I remedy this issue? Any help would be nice.

*Edit*

Please note, I checked the certificate, if there is a URL matching www.domain-name.com. This is what I found in the keystore :

```
#8: ObjectId:IDCriticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: domain-name.com
  DNSName: www.domain-name.com
]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The file urlrewrite.xml is present in ROOT.war in WEB-INF and in ROOT folder as well when its exploded.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ssl-certificates-for-domain-without-www

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69783/always-redirecting-to-https-without-www try these ?

Comment: @JoseK : 2nd link is not useful as it is for Apache web server. For the first link, it deals with certificate issue, but I am looking for redirection, different problem.

Answer (score 1):

`url-rewrite` can only run after the request has reached the server. The TLS handshake (which includes server presenting its certificate to the client) is where the client (browser) checks the server's certificate to see if its hostname matches. If it doesn't match, the browser will show an error to the user.

There are only a few ways to avoid this:

1. Never use the bare domain name in URLs (e.g. always use `www.domain-name.com`)
2. Get a "subject alternative name" added to your certificate for `domain-name.com` in addition to the primary subject name `www.domain-name.com`
3. Get a "wildcard" TLS certificate

**UPDATE**

You have a subject-alternative-name in your TLS certificate? If so, the browser should not be complaining about the hostname.

**UPDATE**

> The error message is:
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from domain-name.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> Advanced :
>
> This server could not prove that it is domain-name.com; its security certificate is from delink.de. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Your router is performing a man-in-the-middle attack against your communications with the server. Your server is properly configured (I checked: it's fine). You should disable any proxying or other similar features on your router, and have it let you get to the Internet without interfering with you.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am also wondering that even if there is an alternative, why is it complaining. Any ideas, thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Firefox 41.0.2, also tested on latest chrome, IE. Cleared entire history and tested, still no luck. Can I send you URL via email I find on your website in your resume.

Comment: I have sent you an email. Thanks a lot. :-)